# AutoIt script hangs for no apparent reason

Tags: array, autoit

I am stuck with this script. For ages it didn't work. And then suddenly it did...and now...on a reinstall...it doesn't work again. It stops on the first winwaitactive line.
The folder is most certainly correct.

```
    #include <File.au3>
    #include <Array.au3>

    AutoItSetOption ("WinTitleMatchMode", 1)
    AutoItSetOption ("WinTextMatchMode", 2)
    AutoItSetOption ("TrayIconDebug", 1)

    $folder = "F:\MUSIC SOFTWARE\BIAB\TRACKS\REALTRACKS\"

    Local $files = _FileListToArray($folder, "*")

    For $i = 1 to UBound($files)
        install($files[$i])
    Next

    Func install($file)
       $pid = Run($file)
       WinWaitActive("Setup - RealTracks", "Welcome to the RealTracks")
       Send("!n")
       WinWait("Setup - RealTracks", "Please read")
       Send("!a")
       Send("!n")
       WinWait("Setup - RealTracks", "When you are ready")
       Send("!n")
       WinWait("Setup - RealTracks", "Where should")
       Send("!n")
       WinWait("Setup - RealTracks", "Setup is now ready")
       Send("!i")
       WinWait("Setup - RealTracks", "Completing")
       Send("!f")
       ProcessWaitClose($pid)
    EndFunc
```

Comment: Quite an obvious solution...

Just needed to add the $folder

    install($folder&$files[$i])

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your script, there's no declaration for the `$File` variable.  Also, you're using `wintitlematchmode, 2` so you don't need to be so explicit in your window notation.  Instead of `Setup - RealTracks` try just `RealTracks`.